# uninitialized constant AppGenerator::Config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm Using 
ruby 2.2.1
rvm 1.21.0
rails 2.3.5

While creating new rails app I'm getting this error

```
uninitialized constant AppGenerator::Config
```

Comment: rails 2.3.5 is sooo old for ruby 2.2.1. Is this a requirements?

Comment: for ruby 1.8.7 I'm getting this error
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)

Comment: @Devux Where does ruby 1.8.7 come into play? Are you using that or 2.2.1 as per your question?

Answer (score 0):

`Rails 2` is not supported anymore. The version that you are using is from more than 5 years ago and contains security bugs and a lot of issues that we don't recommend anyone to use it in a new application.

I recommend to update your rails greater then or equal `Rails 4.0`